# How to check for number and text in a cell using IF OR

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am stuck trying to get an Excel formula to function correctly. What my goal is is to check a cell (D8) for either A) a specific number in an ID number to determine the sex of the student or B) the sex of a foreign student by means of a post-fix on the passport number (-F/-M).

Cell D8 is used to capture the ID/Passport number and D9 is used to populate M/F from the results in D8.

Currently this is working fine on South African ID's using:

```
=IF(--MID(D8,7,1)<5,"F","M")
```

Now I need to add another condition that will check if the cell contains -F and if it does D9 will be F, otherwise it will be M, using:

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-F",D8))
```

The problem I simply cannot seem to fix, is to combine these to conditions on the input of D8.

EDIT: There are 3 variables here: 1. Does the value in D8 start with a number or text. 2. If it starts with a number, is digit number 7 < 5 and 3. If it starts with a letter, does it end with -F or -M.

If digit number 7 in the ID is < 7 return F, else return M.
If the cell value ends with -F return F else return M.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(FIND("-F",D8),FALSE),--MID(D8,7,1)<5),"F","M")
```

If it finds -F, it's a female. If it does not find -F, it will cause an error that the IFERROR catches and outputs male

EDIT see now that you wanted to combine the two. Not sure about the `--` part, but I just copied your formula that you said worked.

EDIT2

```
=IF(LENGHT(D8)>11, IF(--MID(D8,7,1)<5,"F","M"),IF(IFERROR(FIND("-F",D8),FALSE),"F","M"))
```

Comment: The mid is used to check if character 7 is less than 5, this indicator is used to check sex in a SA ID number... It does however not work in the formula you provided. If you have another way to check character 7 AND if -F is found in cell D8 that would be great.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I tested it and found the error. Try it now.

Comment: unfortunetally not. It shows the entire formula in the cell when I enter it out to next cell as opposed to an empty cell ready to take input, so it means there is a problem with the formula

Comment: Are you sure you copy paste the correct way? You can't paste a formula on a cell, you have to paste it in the formula field. What you describe is exactly what happens if you copy paste the wrong way.

Comment: No I actually program on Excel all the time, its just formulas that can get a bit confusing at times, hence the combining of the two, but I most certainly use the formula bar when pasting...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128436/discussion-between-andre-van-rensburg-and-andreas).

Comment: Post a picture of the problem

Comment: @AndrévanRensburg Enter the chat again, I have a question